# CSS Dropdown menu frustrating issue

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7

I've been smashing my head against a wall for about 3 hours now and guessing what's going on isn't working either. Can someone please help me rescue my waning sanity?

Basically in IE7 the second level on this menu just won't stay open when you try to hover over it. I've tried z-indexes, containers with position: relative set, line heights, borders, padding...everything!! What am I missing? ARgg!! Must be something obvious at a guess but my tired brain has just given in.

http://www.sah.org.au/devt/

Thanks for your help!

John.

Comment: Why you moving the child ul to far left instead of making them display:none?

Comment: Saw your comment: * using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isn't read by screen readers */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really is frustrating.

The only (*almost* there) solution I could find was to add a `background-color` to `#menu a`. You can change it to the correct colour on `:hover` for the different links. Or, just move it from `li` to `a`.

Weird, right? It massively helps.

I'm reasonably sure that a perfect solution is going to require (ugly) HTML changes, or writing jQuery to do the same thing (for only IE7).

Comment: Who would have thought setting the colour of something would fix it... what a strange world we live in.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment on the code that says

> /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none
>   isn't read by screen readers */

I found you don't want sub menus got read by screen reader. I did a research and found out most of the screen readers don't read the `visibility:hidden` elements. My suggestion to you is removing the `left:-999em` and replacing it with `visibility:hidden` and `dsiplay:none` together.

Here is the article about screen readers:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fir/